# Template wordpress OnePage mas também paginado

Tags: php, javascript, html, paginação, wordpress-theme

Estou desenvolvendo um template wordpress, e ele tem a seguinte dinâmica, é um site one page, ou seja ancorado. No menu chamo as paginas que são ancoradas do one page, mas no menu eu também chamo paginas que são paginadas, essas eu programei para serem criadas no wordpress, através do page.php.

O problema esta sendo seguinte, quando eu abro site, na parte inicial, eu consigo fazer que os itens do menu que levam para as paginas ancoradas funcionem normalmente. 
Ex: Eu clico em Contato no Menu, a página desce lentamente até a parte do One Page onde está o Contato. Isso esta funcionando perfeitamente quando eu abro o site inicialmente. 
Quando eu clico em serviços, o site vai para a pagina serviços (saindo do One Page). Até ae tudo bem, mas quando eu clico em Contato novamente para voltar pra a página One Page e ir até Contatos, ae ele não consegue voltar, é como se agora ele tentasse fazer o One page Na página Serviços.

O menu eu programei também, para ser criado no Wordpress.

Preciso fazer isso, um site OnePage mas também, um site paginado. Sem ter problemas de ir e voltar das paginas para as ancoras.

Comment: Já tentou algo como "urlIndex#onepage" no link *(desta forma o html sabe que tem 1 ir para a página urlindex e para  ancora onepage?

Comment: Então, o meu Menu esta da seguinte forma. Eu programei ele para ser feito no wordpress. Eu fiz os meus itens do menu como por exemplo:   Serviços (Chama a página criada no wordpress), e tem Contato (Essa eu criei um link personalizado que está "#contato", que funciona só quando esta na onepage, na "index.php").

Comment: Então se colocar o link de contato como "index.php#contato" não funciona ?

Comment: tenta usar o `site_url("#ancora")`no menu, onde precisa ser ancora e `site_url("nome_da_pagina")` onde é página

Comment: Mas eu devo colocar isso na URL do link personalizado do wordpress??
Já tentei colocar index.php#contato mas não deu certo @Bartolomeu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema instalando um plugin.

- Page Links To, esse plugin me da a opção de alterar a URL das minhas paginas e posts. Assim eu crio as páginas, e através da URL eu defino se elas serão parte do OnePage ancoradas ou se são paginadas.

Concluo chamando as páginas criadas normalmente no Menu Wordpress.